# android crash glide-disk-cach

Tags: android, android-glide

When I start my app with internet, the app crashed! When start the app without internet, the app can work, and I refresh, the data can be loaded the app is running without problem. The log as bellow.

--------- beginning of crash

```
2019-01-25 16:07:53.188 25201-25245/com.xuanji.www.dou A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 25245 (glide-disk-cach), pid 25201 (.xuanji.www.dou)
2019-01-25 16:07:53.247 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-01-25 16:07:53.247 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/sirius/sirius:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.019/V10.2.1.0.OEBCNFK:user/release-keys'
2019-01-25 16:07:53.247 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2019-01-25 16:07:53.247 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2019-01-25 16:07:53.247 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG: pid: 25201, tid: 25245, name: glide-disk-cach  >>> com.xuanji.www.dou <<<
2019-01-25 16:07:53.247 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2019-01-25 16:07:53.249 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'unknown bitmap configuration'
2019-01-25 16:07:53.249 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   000000000000629d  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
2019-01-25 16:07:53.249 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
2019-01-25 16:07:53.249 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   c768f3f1fbb6401c  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000001
2019-01-25 16:07:53.249 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG:     x12  ffffffffffffffff  x13  ffffffffffffffff  x14  ff00000000000000  x15  ffffffffffffffff
2019-01-25 16:07:53.249 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000006283900fa8  x17  000000778acfe8c8  x18  00000076ea5f8d04  x19  0000000000006271
2019-01-25 16:07:53.249 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG:     x20  000000000000629d  x21  000000007fffffff  x22  0000000047f6ca00  x23  0000000047f6ca00
2019-01-25 16:07:53.249 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000000  x25  0000000000000000  x26  00000076ea5ff588  x27  0000000000000009
2019-01-25 16:07:53.249 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG:     x28  00000076ea5ff588  x29  00000076ea5f8090  x30  000000778acb413c
2019-01-25 16:07:53.249 25248-25248/? A/DEBUG:     sp   00000076ea5f8050  pc   000000778acb4158  pstate 0000000060000000
2019-01-25 16:07:53.529 8846-8846/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.qihoo360.apm.apmdatamanager.ApmDataProvider
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.replace)    
    .error(R.drawable.replace)
    .override(mWidth, mHeight);   // I add the Bitmap dimensions, the                        //problem solved.
Glide.with(mContext).load(item.getStrCoverUrl()).apply(options).into(iv);
```

Comment: I add the Bitmap dimensions, the problem solved. Maybe the Bitmap lead to out of memory.